# background image not cover menu icon after resizing

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am implementing a toggle navbar. The side nav bar will become a hamburger menu icon in smaller screen size.
The background image does not cover the menu icon in smaller screen size. But it looks fine with the side navbar in a larger screen.

```
content: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        padding: theme.spacing(3),
        fontSize: 20,
        backgroundImage: `url(${bg})`,
        backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
        backgroundPosition: "center center",
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
        height: "100%"

    },



 drawer: {
        [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
            width: drawerWidth,
            flexShrink: 0,
        },
    },

    menuButton: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
        [theme.breakpoints.up('md')]: {
            display: 'none',
        },
    },
    drawerPaper: {
        width: drawerWidth,
        opacity:0.8
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set [Background Attachment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment) back to `scroll` and not `fixed`.